# 2-dimensional JSON array to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have a JSON encoded array that looks like this (it came from a 2d PHP string array):

```
[
[
    "a1",
    "a2",
    "a3",
    "a4"
],
[
    "b1",
    "b2",
    "b3",
    "b4"
],
[
    "c1",
    "c2",
    "c3",
    "c4"
]
]
```

It has been validated on http://jsonlint.com/

Now I want to send this array to another page by Ajax and convert it back to a 2d PHP array.
After making a JSON array I do the following (where myJsonArray is the name I gave to the array after making it into a Javascript array.:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "somewhere.php",
       data: {jsonArray : myJsonArray},
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(msg){
         alert( msg); 
       }

     });
 }
```

And then in somewhere.php I do:

```
 $json_array = $_GET['jsonArray'];

 $myArray = json_decode($json_array,true);
```

But when I echo the result I just get

```
[Object object]
```

I'm not sure how to recreate the PHP array.

EDIT: 
How to make myJsonArray:

```
<?php
$array = json_encode($original_array);

echo "var myJsonArray = ". $array . ";\n";
?>
```

I would also like to point out that for tesitng purposes, in the alert box I made it print myJsonArray on success, and it did indeed print out the array as expected.

Comment: How do you create `myJsonArray`?

Comment: *"After making a JSON array..."* How did you do this? Sure seems like that's where the problem would be. Seems like you've left out the most important code.

Comment: Did you check how JsonArray looks like in html? Also did you try to echo not decoded $_GET['jsonArray'];

Comment: @Pankaj Khairnar - the output is a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4,c1,c2,c3,c4

Comment: I updated my answer.  Please have a look.

Comment: When I tried to replicate it locally, I am getting normal php and don't even need to use json_decode, when you are making ajax call check what is going to server using Firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Object object]" is javascript evaluating an object as a string.

When you pass the optional "true" into json_decode, you are telling it that it is an associative array.  But you really want an array of arrays.

I am sure that if you use JSON.stringify to print to your log, you would have the correct data, except the outer brackets would be "{..}".

Comment: You are correct. JSON.stringify worked, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: The actual solution here is to not pass true into json_decode().  The JSON.stringify() was just to help you see the data.  Unlike php, javascript treats associative arrays as objects.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried executing  below code snippet for decoding json content as specified above and it is working fine for me.

```
<?php
               $a=array(array("a1","a2","a3","a4"),array("b1","b2","b3","b4"),array("c1","c2","c3","c4"));
               $json_content=json_encode($a);
              $json_array=json_decode($json_content,true);
               echo '<pre>';
                print_r($json_array);
?>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, and doesn't address the question.